# Updating a field in the Nintex sharepoint task list from the Nintex workflow

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-workflow, nintex-workflow

I am creating a Nintex workflow in SharePoint 2010.
I have a requirement to update a field in the Nintext SharePoint Task List from one of the action in work flow. Is it possible achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

A Nintex workflow task list, is no different than a Sharepoint list, so yes you can update an item in the task list. Simply use the relevant action in your workflow to update an item in another list.